# MySQL: Comparision between huge tables

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, mysql-5.1

I got two tables, let them be *data* and *newdata*. My query should select all rows from *data*, where a *price* of type double is less then another double-field *price* in *newdata*. Every row in the tables is identified by its primary key *articleno*.

My query for doing so looks like this (not actual query because in live scenario are many more columns to select, but the comparision is basically like this):

```
SELECT
    data.articleno,
    data.articledesc
    data.price
FROM
    data,
    newdata
WHERE
    data.articleno = newdata.articleno
    AND data.price < newdata.price
```

With limit set to 10 or small tables, this works just fine. But the tables I need to work on have sizes up to 120k rows. The last time I run this query on both tables containing 50k rows, it took about 180 seconds to fetch all the data.

Question: How do I speed this up? I thought about doing a JOIN, and then do the selection with the comparison, but shouldn't this be even worse? And: Why is this comparision that slow? Is it a double thing, should I use float instead (if that is faster)?

Need to work on MySQL 5.1 by the way.

Comment: What indexes do you have on those columns? What is the  `explain select ...` output? If you don't have an index on `price` then add one.

Comment: Put a composed index on `data(articleno,price)` and one on `newdata(articleno,price)`.These should speed things up if they are not there already.

Comment: It seems that I had wrong (or broken) indices. Dropped all of them and recreated, now faster than light. Thank you for the hint, I knew I had them, but didn't make them responsible for this issue.